# IFTTT feed rss how does it work?

Tags: feed

I am using IFTTT and feed for extracting information from a rss file. Anybody know how the IFTTT feed ingredients are chosen in the rss file ? How can we say to IFTTT to search a specific xml code like  ?
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Ifttt work like "if this than that"

So when as if you use condition if it check feed at period of time frequently and when there is new data on rss feed it parse it and check for that method and send it over there.

at the time of selecting that method you can choose the type data you want to parse from rss feed including TITLE, Description and other many tags are there.

If you select title only title will be parse from feed.